# How to publish map on web so that anybody can view it

Tags: geoserver

I want to develop a web application which will allow any person to view map as per their interest combining different parameters.
For example- I have literacy wise district map of some state and I wish to give an user interface(web based) which allow them to select district of their choice and represent map based on required query which is literacy in this case.

I am trying geo server but i am not sure this will help or not.

Answer (score 2):

Try nextgis.com. You can create own map via web UI or exporting from QGIS (see http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/toc.html). If exist web map functionality is not enough, you can use lefleat (https://github.com/nextgis/nextgisweb_tinymap) or openlayers to visualize data from your web GIS. 
Also you can install NextGIS Web on your own server (see http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/sysadmin.html).